# Download files with lftp seems not aware of disk full at my side. How can I fix that?

Tags: lftp

Using lftp I download files from a remote server (mget -E) to my local server. When my local disk is full, I would think lftp would get an error from the OS (CentOS7) and try later to download or complete the download. Instead, lftp just got on writing 0 byte files at my side. Is there anything I can do to let lftp stop with an error when my local disk has 0 bytes free?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:
**Settings**: On startup, lftp executes ~/.lftprc and ~/.lftp/rc (or ~/.config/lftp/rc if ~/.lftp does not exist). You can place aliases and 'set' commands there. Some people prefer to see full protocol debug: use 'debug' to turn on debugging.

In Settings -> **xfer:disk-full-fatal (boolean)** - when true, lftp *aborts* a transfer if it cannot write the target file to disk because of full disk or quota; when false, lftp waits for disk space to be freed.

This is from the (lengthy) lftp manual; one version here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Initially xfer:disk-full-fatal was not set. So, according to the manual, lftp should have been waiting for disk space to be freed. But it didn't: it just went on writing files of 0 bytes and erasing files with the same filename at the source.

Comment: Did you try to set it to "false"? Otherwise: lftp.yar.ru/author.html

Comment: Thanks again, msr. I just changed it to 'false'. Tomorrow in the early hours I will test, both false and true.